# Cross-validation as strategy for training

Tags: cross-validation, bias, small-sample

Let's say I have a classification model to be trained and a relatively small dataset. The data is splited in k-folds (eg. k=5), in such a way that:

- **A**, **B** and **C** are used for training, **D** for testing and the trained model is evaluated on **E**.
- **B**, **C** and **D** are used for training, **E** for testing and the trained model is evaluated on **A**.
- **C**, **D** and **E** are used for training, **A** for testing and the trained model is evaluated on **B**.
- **D**, **E** and **A** are used for training, **B** for testing and the trained model is evaluated on **C**.
- **E**, **A** and **B** are used for training, **C** for testing and the trained model is evaluated on **D**.

The final result of this experiment is a statistical summary of all k-folds. In this way, no data would be "wasted" on training only and the final result profits from a lower statistical uncertainty.

Would that make sense, from a statistical point of view? I'm curious specifically about some potential bias I'm not foreseeing...